# AngularJs code for show/hide div's

Tags: angularjs

Here my two div's are as follows:

```
<div class="login">
UserName:<input type="text" name="uname"><br>
Password:<input type="password" name="pwd"><br>
<input type="submit" value="login"><br>
<a href="#" id="register">SignUp for new User</a>

</div>
<div class="signUp">
FirstName:<input type="text" name="fname"><br>
Lastname:<input type="text" name="lname"><br>
Password:<input type="password" name="pwd"><br>
<button>SignUp</button>

</div>
```

And my script in jQuery as follows:

```
 $(document).ready(function()
  {  
  $(".signUp").hide();
     $("#register").click(function() {
        $(".signUp").show();
        $(".login").hide();
     });  
   });
```

I want the same functionality using angularjs. Can anyone help me out..

Comment: please read http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial and come back with a real question, thanks

Comment: You asked the [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17296550/switch-between-two-divs-in-angularjs) some 5 hours ago and it was closed for "being too lazy". Do you expect different result this time?

Comment: As iam new to AngularJS im finding it difficult to achieve that functionality.

Comment: As @mb21 pointed out, go through the tutorial and you'll be on your way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google ng-show and ng-hide.  Basically you want to create a variable in your model that represents whether these are shown.  ng-show/hide bind to this variable and automatically take care of the div's visibility when the variable's value changes.  Also, look at the ng-click tag for your register button.